# Acess local scope

Tags: jquery, events, click, put

I need access the reservas inside the PUT request to send to the url /datas. Anyone knows how?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .starter-template {
            margin-top: 150px;
        }

        .checkbox {
            width: 40px;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-  collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Banco de dados</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/">Cadastros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="datas">Datas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>✓</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                <div id="checkbox"></div>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    //async: false,
    url: 'https://app.myurl.com/reservas',
    success:function(reservas){

        reservas.forEach (function (reserva) {
            var reservas = [];


            reservas.push('<tr class="reservas">');
            reservas.push('<td> <input type="checkbox" id="salvar"/> </td>');
            reservas.push('<td>' + reserva._id + '</td>');
            reservas.push('<td>' + reserva.nome + '</td>');
            reservas.push('<td>' + reserva.email + '</td>');
            reservas.push('</tr>');

            $('tbody').append(reservas.join(""));

        })
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

And them i have the PUT request inside the click event.

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#salvar', function(){
       alert('Salvo!');

       $.ajax({

            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost/datas',
            //async: false,
            data: {
                id: reserva._id,
                nome: reserva.nome,
                email: reserva.email
            },
            sucess:function (success) {
                console.log('success')
            },
            error:function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});






</script>
```

if you can direct me, I appreciate it =)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are these two files?

Comment: Inside my html.index, before the end of the body, Kumar.. The GET request it's working perfectly, because i get the data from other URL and just arrange it in the html..

Comment: Call me Praveen. Oh, but this is accessible only after the AJAX call. Can you post the full code in a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: You either need to create a variable that will be in scope for both methods and set its value to the reservas, or you will have to get the data from the DOM using jQuery. Either will work.

Comment: You also seem to be redeclaring `reservas` in the `GET - forEach`?

Comment: I don't have idea how to make a global variable for this.. helps?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the name reservas for two thinks Rob :B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a global variable here as there are many potential `reserva` being returned by the `GET` however you can declare a variable as `global` by declaring it outside of any other functions and code somewhere before your `GET` like this:

```
var myGlobalReserva;
// Then all your other code here.
```

What you want to actually do I am guessing it the following, use "data-attributes" http://api.jquery.com/data/ to store the relevant data on a particular "reserva" which you then append to the DOM.  Note that it is not valid to have more than 1 element with the same ID so I have changed it to `class="salvar"`.  Then in the "PUT" you would get the data-attributes values.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    //async: false,
    url: 'https://app.myurl.com/reservas',
    success:function(reservas){

        reservas.forEach (function (reserva) {
            var reservasHTML = [];


            reservasHTML.push('<tr class="reservas">');
            reservasHTML.push('<td> <input type="checkbox" class="salvar" data-id="' + reserva._id + '" data-nome="' + reserva.nome + '" data-email="' + reserva.email + '"/> </td>');
            reservasHTML.push('<td>' + reserva._id + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('<td>' + reserva.nome + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('<td>' + reserva.email + '</td>');
            reservasHTML.push('</tr>');

            $('tbody').append(reservas.join(""));

        })
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});


$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.salvar', function(){
       alert('Salvo!');
       var clickedBox = $(this);

       $.ajax({

            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost/datas',
            //async: false,
            data: {
                id: clickedBox.data('id'),
                nome: clickedBox.data('nome'),
                email: clickedBox.data('email')
            },
            sucess:function (success) {
                console.log('success')
            },
            error:function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```